# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException with ICEFaces

Tags: spring, icefaces

Im getting this exception when the view try to renders, im using the icefaces validators tags in a simple ice form, also im using spring to instantiate the managed beans but it is working correctly in other pages, SO i dont feel spring is the problem ... this is the exception :

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Implement SWF integration    at
>   com.icesoft.util.SeamUtilities.getSpringFlowId(SeamUtilities.java:542)
>     at
>   com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:146)
>     at
>   com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.renderkit.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:42)
>     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RendererWrapper.encodeBegin(RendererWrapper.java:50)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:824)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1641)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at     etc.....

This the code of my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:include src="generic-modules/header.xhtml" />
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="generic-modules/header-navigation.xhtml" />
    <div id="bd">
        <div class="registration">
            <div class="form">
                <ice:form>
                    <ice:inputText id="Name" value="#{applicant.name}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="45" minimum="5" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="nameError" for="name" />
                    <br />
                    <ice:inputText id="Address" value="#{applicant.address}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="45" minimum="10" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="addressError" for="address" />
                    <br />
                    <ice:inputText id="Workplace" value="#{applicant.workplace}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="45" minimum="10" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="workplaceError" for="workplace" />
                    <br />
                    <ice:inputText id="Telephone" value="#{applicant.telephone}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="10" minimum="8" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="telephoneError" for="telephone" />
                    <br/>
                    <ice:inputText id="Photo" value="#{applicant.photo}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="80" minimum="2" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="photoError" for="photo" />
                    <br/>
                    <ice:inputText id="Username" value="#{applicant.username}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="10" minimum="8" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="usernameError" for="username" />
                    <br/>
                    <ice:inputText id="Password" value="#{applicant.password}" partialSubmit="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="10" minimum="8" />
                    </ice:inputText>
                    <ice:message style="color: red;" id="passwordError" for="password" />
                    <br/>
                    <ice:commandButton value="Register" actionListener="#{applicant.save}" />
                    <br />
                    <!-- <ice:outputText value="Age: " />
                    <ice:outputText value="" /> -->
                </ice:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I dont know what is wrong because im only using the code of the icefaces tutorials, i appreciate if anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, I don't believe there is a solution to this issue.  I was working on the same thing yesterday for about 8 hours.  See [this](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-6599?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) page on the icefaces bug tracker:  .  They actually have the issue marked resolved, and have tutorials that claim that icefaces integrates with SWF 2.X, but the simple fact of the matter is this little line of code in their `seamutilities.java class`:

```
if (true)
{
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Implement SWF integration");
}
```

I've tried running various version of icefaces before the fix was implemented on up through the current beta, and I still have issues.  I'm going to say presently, the two are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

i am getting this exception with ice forums, and as a workaround i use jsf form instead of iceforums and so far it's working fine with me.